# How to make comment box (like in facebook comment box) in django

Tags: django

I want to add a comment box in my item_view.html. A comment box like in facebook that doesn't need to refresh the page. Is it possible in django?

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea is:

1) Use ajax to send post message to the server. [Read jquery's ajax function](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

2) Then, do whatever the server needs to do to add the comment to the database.

3) Fetch the list of comments on the particular topic via ajax again, and display.

This is a subset of kind of architecture called SPA (single page application) btw.

Comment: Thank you brother. I will try this one. When it comes to messaging/chat, do I need to use ajax too?